# MySQL replica stuck processing a COMMIT

Tags: mysql

I am running MySQL `5.7.33` in AWS RDS, one master and one replica. It's been working fine for many months. However today my replica has been stuck processing an event from the master for > 1 hour so I looked at the output from `SHOW SLAVE STATUS` which is:

```
               Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                  Master_Host: 172.16.2.249
                  Master_User: rdsrepladmin
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: mysql-bin-changelog.219773
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 4937232
               Relay_Log_File: relaylog.001505
                Relay_Log_Pos: 90634431
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin-changelog.219716
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB:
          Replicate_Ignore_DB:
           Replicate_Do_Table:
       Replicate_Ignore_Table: mysql.plugin,mysql.rds_monitor,mysql.rds_sysinfo,innodb_memcache.cache_policies,mysql.rds_history,innodb_memcache.config_options,mysql.rds_configuration,mysql.rds_replication_status
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error:
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 90659902
              Relay_Log_Space: 10557463369
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File:
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File:
           Master_SSL_CA_Path:
              Master_SSL_Cert:
            Master_SSL_Cipher:
               Master_SSL_Key:
        Seconds_Behind_Master: 4162
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error:
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error:
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids:
             Master_Server_Id: 144344952
                  Master_UUID: 0b6e346a-85a2-11ec-8285-0631e7645682
             Master_Info_File: mysql.slave_master_info
                    SQL_Delay: 0
          SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
      Slave_SQL_Running_State: Reading event from the relay log
           Master_Retry_Count: 86400
                  Master_Bind:
      Last_IO_Error_Timestamp:
     Last_SQL_Error_Timestamp:
               Master_SSL_Crl:
           Master_SSL_Crlpath:
           Retrieved_Gtid_Set:
            Executed_Gtid_Set:
                Auto_Position: 0
         Replicate_Rewrite_DB:
                 Channel_Name:
           Master_TLS_Version:
```

Looking in `information_schema.INNODB_TRX` revealed:

```
                    trx_id: 871372620
                 trx_state: RUNNING
               trx_started: 2023-03-03 10:01:37
     trx_requested_lock_id: NULL
          trx_wait_started: NULL
                trx_weight: 216476
       trx_mysql_thread_id: 5
                 trx_query: NULL
       trx_operation_state: NULL
         trx_tables_in_use: 1
         trx_tables_locked: 1
          trx_lock_structs: 4011
     trx_lock_memory_bytes: 368848
           trx_rows_locked: 212465
         trx_rows_modified: 212465
   trx_concurrency_tickets: 0
       trx_isolation_level: READ COMMITTED
         trx_unique_checks: 1
    trx_foreign_key_checks: 1
trx_last_foreign_key_error: NULL
 trx_adaptive_hash_latched: 0
 trx_adaptive_hash_timeout: 0
          trx_is_read_only: 0
trx_autocommit_non_locking: 0
```

If I refreshed the output of the above query, the `trx_rows_locked` and `trx_rows_modified` were changing, implying the replica was actually processing the event. I downloaded all the binary logs from the master and can find this entry for `90659902` in `mysql-bin-changelog.219716`:

```
#230303 10:01:35 server id 144344952  end_log_pos 90659902 CRC32 0x18166a0e     Xid = 12591879906
COMMIT/*!*/;
# at 90659902
```

How do I trace this `COMMIT` back to the query/queries involved? The server is typically very busy so there is lots of noise in the binary logs.

Comment: you will find the insert or any operation above of the commit which MySQL replication has applied & now applying commit overall changes.
try using show event in 'binarlog' from 'position'

Comment: @JYOTIRAJAI the query above in the binary log is a nothingburger - it's an INSERT of a single row on a small table with no triggers

Comment: Is GTID enabled ?

Comment: @JYOTIRAJAI `gtid_mode` is currently `OFF_PERMISSIVE`